# Android stream video with widgets in foreground

Tags: android, video, streaming

I want to stream video on an android tablet live updating widgets such as a leaderboard. The attached image link is an example of what I want to accomplish.  What tools are needed to accomplish this goal? How do I technically accomplish this goal.

Thanks,

Moses

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABXQf.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, it's an "App" that you are trying to build and not a widget placed on the homescreen.
Assuming that you need to:

- Establish a `socket` connection with the app to regularly push the scores. You can also get the scores and other dynamic information updated via an `HTTP API` that is polled regularly but it isn't battery efficient.
- Break down the view into smaller pieces which will be put together to form the required view. For example, the `LeaderboardView` will be it's own view, `DistanceView`, `CaloriesView`, `OutputView` and `ResistanceView` will be custom views inflated individually and added into the `ParentView`.
- You can use the default `MediaPlayer` class provided to stream the video OR alternatively use libraries such as `ExoPlayer` to help you achieve the same, depending on the level customisation you need.